# Infinity norm inequality in continuous function space.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

There's this inequality that i find intuitive but can't seem to prove it nor unprove it. So for $ f: [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function  and $ L : [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ an affine function that satisfies $L(0) = f(0)$ and $L(1) = f(1)$. The norm is defined by $\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$. Is the following true?

$$ \lVert f - L \rVert_\infty \le \lVert f \rVert_\infty $$

$f - L$ represents for me a skew transformation of the function f. So it seems natural that it wouldn't surpass the maximum value of f itself.

Comment: By affine function, do you mean $L(x) = (1-x)f(0) + xf(1)$?

Comment: Yes, I was just too lazy to calculate it.

Comment: What if we take $f(x) = 8x(1-x) - 1$? Then the minima and maxima of $f$ are $f(0) = f(1) = -1$ and $f(1/2) = 1$, so $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$. But $L$ is the constant function $-1$, so $\|f-L\|_{\infty} = |f(1/2) - L(1/2)| = 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true. For the sake of simplicity, allow me to work on $[-\pi, \pi]$ instead of $[0,1]$. Let $f(x) = \cos x$. Clearly, $\| f \|_\infty = 1$. Notice that, in general, $L(x) = (f(\pi) - f(-\pi))x + f(-\pi)$ so, in this case, $L(x) = \cos (-\pi) = -1$. It follows that $\| f - L \| _\infty \ge 2$ because $(f-L) (0) = 1 - (-1) = 2$, so clearly $2 = \| f-L \|_\infty \nleq \| f \| = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f$ defined by the graph $(0,0), ({1 \over 2}, -1), (1,1)$. Then
$L(x) = x$, $\|f\|_\infty = 1$ and
$\|f-L\|_\infty =
 {3 \over 2}$.